# Is it possible to have one facebook app link to two android app deeply?

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

the scenario of my problem is:

1. I have two android apps for the same application that one is the free version, and another one is the full version.
2. I created one facebook app for this android application.
3. Now, I want to use the deep linking feature provided by facebook app, and it did work fine with my free version app.
   (Deep linking means that, when user click my app's icon on facebook, they will be redirected to my android app or market automatically.)
4. However, when I wanted to add this feature to my full version app, I found that facebook app seems just to provide one quota for deep linking with android app. 
   Because I can just fill in one unique package name in the app dashboard configuration page.

---

Therefore, my question is that:

If I hope my app will have two versions(free and full), and also can link with my facebook app.

Should I **implement the In-app Billing service** in my only one app, and **not to make two versions of app**?

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the preferred method would be to have one version with an in-app purchase option. There's some good discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145005/how-to-keep-free-paid-version-of-the-app-separate-in-subversion) about ways to separate the functionality and how to maintain the project.

Comment: thanks for you reply!
Yah~ Finally I decide to the in-app purchase.